# codeigniter controller not recognizing passed variable

Tags: php, javascript, html, codeigniter

I don't know if I formulated this question correctly but let me try to explain myself better.
I have following menu on my page that outputs new result once new selection is choosen:
[image: select menus]

`Izaberite pol:` and `Izaberite studente:` contains 3 options each `oba, zenski, muski` and `oba, stari, novi` respectively.

I've added some Javascript to recognise option changing and automatically call controller action:

```
$("select.filter").change(function () {
    var str = "";
    $("select option:selected").each(function () {
        str += $(this).attr('value') + "/";
    });
    window.open("http://vipassana-srbija.comli.com/index.php/login/trust/"+str,"_self");
});
```

As you can see from Javacript code it will call controller's Login trust function:

```
public function trust($tabela="letnji",$pol="oba", $student="oba"){

    $data['rezultat']=  $this->prijava_model->zgrabi_tabelu($tabela,$pol,$student);
    $data['tabela']=$tabela;
    $data['pol']=$pol;
    $data['student']=$student;

    $prijavljen = $this->session->userdata('prijavljen');
    if($prijavljen)
    {
        $this->load->view('prijava/trust.php', $data);  
    }
    else
    {
        redirect('login');
    }
}
```

Further you will notice that it uses `Prijava_model` model's `zgrabi_tabelu` function:

```
function zgrabi_tabelu($tabela,$pol,$student){
    $upit_rezultat=array();

    if($pol=="oba" && $student="oba")
        $upit = $this->db->get($tabela);
    else if($pol!="oba" && $student!="oba")
        $upit=$this->db->get_where($tabela,array('pol'=>$pol,'stari_novi_student'=>$student));
    else if($pol!="oba" && $student=="oba")
        $upit=$this->db->get_where($tabela, array('pol'=>$pol));
    else if( $pol=="oba" && $student!="oba")
        ;//$upit=$this->db->get_where($tabela, array('stari_novi_student'=>$student));

    foreach($upit->result() as $red){
        array_push($upit_rezultat, $red);
    }

    return $upit_rezultat;
}
```

And I think that here in the model's `zgrabi_tabelu` function lies problem as every possible combination works fine, except for the last one, when I try to grab data by changing only last selection menu `Izaberite studente:` leaving all other options intact:

[image: doesn't work1]
***&&***
[image: doesn't work2]
***WILL NOT WORK***

but when I change previous field `Izaberite pol:` to anything beside `Oba` it will work fine:

[image: works]

And lastly let me provide you with HTML of menu items:

```
<div>
    <label>Izaberite kurs:</label>
    <select class="kurs" id="kurs_datum">
        <option value="letnji" selected='selected'>Letnji kurs(27.6 - 7.7.2012)</option>
        <option value="jesenji" >Jesenji kurs(10.10 - 21.10.2012)</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div>   
    <label>Izaberite pol:</label>
    <select class="filter" id="pol">
        <option value="oba" selected='selected'>Oba</option>
        <option value="zenski" >Ženski</option>
        <option value="muski" >Muški</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div>
    <label>Izaberite studente:</label>
    <select class="filter" id="student">
        <option value="oba" selected='selected'>Oba</option>
        <option value="novi" >Novi</option>
        <option value="stari" >Stari</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Hope this makes sense. I will gladly clarify this further if necessary.
Any help appreciated.

Comment: when you say not work, what do you mean?  what is the response in the network tab/firebug?  is the ajax not working or is it a problem with your server side code?

Comment: I mean that when I choose any of those 2 combination on above images output doesn't update, even though page controller's function gets executed and page loaded, so I think it is something wrong with the logic inside model's `zgrabi_tabelu` function but I cannot see what.. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function zgrabi_tabelu($tabela,$pol,$student){
$upit_rezultat=array();

if($pol=="oba" && $student="oba")
    $upit = $this->db->get($tabela);
else if($pol!="oba" && $student!="oba")
    $upit=$this->db->get_where($tabela,array('pol'=>$pol,'stari_novi_student'=>$student));
else if($pol!="oba" && $student=="oba")
    $upit=$this->db->get_where($tabela, array('pol'=>$pol));
else if( $pol=="oba" && $student!="oba")
    ;//$upit=$this->db->get_where($tabela, array('stari_novi_student'=>$student));

foreach($upit->result() as $red){
    array_push($upit_rezultat, $red);
}

return $upit_rezultat;
}
```

You left out a = on the first line...

```
if($pol=="oba" && $student="oba")
```

should be

```
if($pol=="oba" && $student=="oba")
```

I believe the IF function will return false because its a false operator.

Comment: Yes!!! That's all I needed, Eagle's eyes!!! Thanks for looking into it my friend.

Answer (score 2):

In your jquery call to open a new window, i think you want to remove that comma and put a slash there

so change this:

```
window.open("http://vipassana-srbija.comli.com/index.php/login/trust/"+str,"_self");
```

to:

```
window.open("http://vipassana-srbija.comli.com/index.php/login/trust/"+str+"/_self");
```

Comment: I don't see how that can be problem if it works for any other combination beside those two I listed above??? Am I missing something here?? Thanks

Comment: Well, he is right, its correct to change this, but it wont break anything if it isnt corrected.

Answer (score 0):

An additional note, where you're calling your view '$this->load->view('prijava/trust.php', $data);'  - should trust.php not be just trust - CI adds .php to the end when 'requiring' in views.

Comment: It doesn't matter either way. With or without the .php it will use the same file. At least with code igniter 2.x.

Comment: Merely an observation, I don't put .php